# Flutter - Syncing Offline Data with Online Server (Complete Solution)

Tags: flutter, architecture, offline, offlineapps

I am currently building a **Flutter Application** where I need a complete **Offline First Solution**. I can already cache the data coming from the server and display to the user when there's no **Internet Connection**.

The problem is that I don't really know how to properly handle the cases where I need to **Post, Update or Delete Data** when there's no Internet Connection.

I am currently using **GetX** for **State Management**, **Moor** as **Local Database**.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your task?